# How to get View from Matcher<View>

Tags: java, kotlin, automation, android-espresso

How do I get the View from a Matcher?

I need to get the bitmap from a specific element which findbyview is not giving specifically but I could get it by specifying more matchers

Comment: can you upload your code snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `check` method of `ViewInteraction` and implement a custom `ViewAssertion`

Example in Kotlin:

```
onView(TODO("ADD YOUR MATCHER")).check { view, noView ->
    // Get bitmap here
}
```

Example in Java:

```
onView(/* TODO("ADD YOUR MATCHER") */).check(new ViewAssertion() {
    @Override
    public void check(View view, NoMatchingViewException noViewFoundException) {
        // Get bitmap here
    }
});
```